# Prove that determinant of matrix is non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let's consider sequence $(c_n)$ such that $c_{n + 1} > c_n$ and different numbers $x_0, x_1,..., x_n \in [a, b]$ such that $a + c_1 > 0$. I want to prove that

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{x_1 + c_1}, \frac{1}{x_1 + c_2}, \frac{1}{x_1 + c_3},...,\frac{1}{x_1 + c_n} \\
\frac{1}{x_2 + c_1}, \frac{1}{x_2 + c_2}, \frac{1}{x_2 + c_3},...,\frac{1}{x_2 + c_n}, \\
\dots \\
\frac{1}{x_n + c_1}, \frac{1}{x_n + c_2}, \frac{1}{x_n + c_3},...,\frac{1}{x_n + c_n}
\end{pmatrix} \neq 0
$$

**My work so far**

My first idea was to prove it by induction since for $n = 1$ we have determinant equal to $\frac{1}{x_1 + c_1} \neq 0$  and for $n  = 2$ we have determinant $\frac{(c_2 - c_1)(x_2 - x_1)}{(x_1 + c_1)(x_2 + c_2)(x_2 + c_1)(x_1 + c_2)} \neq 0 $ since $x_2 \neq x_1$ and $c_2 > c_1$.

However, by assuming our theorem for dimension $n$ I didn't know how to generalize it to dimension $n + 1$. Moreover, I tried to calculate directly this determinant also by induction but I couldn't observe any pattern to assume. Could you please give me a hand in proving this theorem?

Comment: It looks like your matrix has $n+1$ rows and $n$ columns.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I updated my question so now it makes sense

Comment: @MartinR There you go!